# Search is not being updated

Tags: reactjs, react-native, api, react-state, react-native-elements

I am using [the meal database](https://www.themealdb.com/api.php).The data from the link is not being updated after search. But if I console.log the search input, I can see the new link.

That's my API for searching:

```
API_URL_SEARCH="https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s="
```

Thats search page:

```
function Meals({ navigation}) {

const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState('');

const handleChange = (inputText) => {
    setSearchInput(inputText);
    };

const { loading, error, data } = useFetch(config.API_URL_SEARCH + searchInput);


const handleMealSelect = idMeal => {
    navigation.navigate("MealDetail", {idMeal})
}

const renderMeals = ({item}) =>  <Meal meal={item} onSelect={() => handleMealSelect(item.idMeal)}/>

if(loading) {
    return <Loading/>;
}

if(error) {
    return <Error/>;
}

return(
    <View>
        <SearchBar
            placeholder="Type Here..."
            onChangeText={handleChange}
            value={searchInput} />

        <FlatList keyExtractor={(meals) => meals.id} data={data.meals} renderItem={renderMeals}/>
    </View>
)
}
```

Thats meal component:

```
const Meal= ({meal, onSelect}) => {
return(
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.container} onPress={onSelect}>
        <ImageBackground
         style={styles.image}
         source={{uri: meal.strMealThumb}}
         imageStyle={{borderTopLeftRadius:10, borderTopRightRadius:10}} />
        <Text style={styles.title}>{meal.strMeal}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
)
}
```

Here is useFetch for getting data and getting loading and error situations just in case of.

```
function useFetch(url) {

const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
const [error, setError] = useState();

const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
    const {data: responseData} = await axios.get(url);
    setData(responseData);
    setLoading(false); }
    catch (error) {
        setError(error.message);
        setLoading(false);
    }
};

useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
}, []);

return {error, loading, data};
};
```

Comment: How is useFetch implemented?

Comment: Edited the post and added the useFetch